# How to have a transition for filterable gallery?

Tags: javascript

I have made a simple filterable gallery using vanilla Js.

---

### Here is the link: https://codepen.io/pexeixv/pen/QWGGPMb

---

The filtering is done by class name. The filtering works fine, however, does not have any transition. The images appear and disappear all of a sudden. I have tried using `transition: all 300ms ease-in-out`.
It does not work and I know it's not supposed to in this case.

---

Is there any way to achieve the type of effect shown here? https://codepen.io/pexeixv/pen/oNxPrNo
If possible only vanilla Js has to be used. Not a hard rule.

Comment: Its best practice to not link to an external site with your code. Instead, [edit] your question, pasting all code [correctly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `animate()`, `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

```js
images = document.querySelectorAll('.img')

function filter(color) {
    if (color == 'all') {
        images.forEach(image => {
            $(".img." + image.classList[1]).fadeIn();
            $(".img." + image.classList[1]).animate({
              width: "100",
              height: "100"
            });
        })
    } else
        images.forEach(image => {
            if (image.classList.contains(color)){
                $(".img." + image.classList[1]).fadeIn();
                $(".img." + image.classList[1]).animate({
                  width: "100",
                  height: "100"
                });
                
            }else {
              $(".img." + image.classList[1]).animate({
                  width: "0",
                  height: "0"
                });
              $(".img." + image.classList[1]).fadeOut();
            }
        })
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700;900&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: Poppins;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  background: lightblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
a.all {
  background: grey;
}
a.blue {
  background: blue;
}
a.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
a.red {
  background: red;
}
a.green {
  background: green;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}
.wrapper .buttonsContainer {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
.wrapper .imagesContainer {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
.wrapper .img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper .img.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.wrapper .img.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
.wrapper .img.red {
  background: red;
}
.wrapper .img.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="buttonsContainer">
            <a onClick="filter('all')" class='all'>All</a>
            <a onClick="filter('green')" class='green'>Green</a>
            <a onClick="filter('blue')" class='blue'>Blue</a>
            <a onClick="filter('yellow')" class='yellow'>Yellow</a>
            <a onClick="filter('red')" class='red'>Red</a>
        </div>
        <div class="imagesContainer">
            <div class="img blue"></div>
            <div class="img red"></div>
            <div class="img green greener"></div>
            <div class="img yellow"></div>
            <div class="img blue"></div>
            <div class="img red"></div>
            <div class="img green"></div>
            <div class="img yellow"></div>
            <div class="img blue"></div>
            <div class="img red"></div>
            <div class="img green"></div>
            <div class="img yellow"></div>
            <div class="img blue"></div>
            <div class="img red"></div>
            <div class="img green"></div>
            <div class="img yellow"></div>
            <div class="img blue"></div>
            <div class="img red"></div>
            <div class="img green"></div>
            <div class="img yellow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the attempt, but I think it's not animating quite well.
See if you can fix it.
https://codepen.io/pexeixv/pen/oNYYKYE

Comment: @GavinPereira what seems to be the problem to you?